# Both headphone audio channels are played in one ear

Tags: audio, headphones

I've been using my Superlux HD 681 headphones normally for a while but suddenly, one of the ears no longer works. After testing by playing audio through each channel separately, I found out that both the left and right audio channels are played through the left ear, where the right channel is slightly quieter than the left channel. I've tried adjusting the audio balance but the right ear still plays no sound at all. I also made sure the plug is fully plugged into the jack and bent the whole wire to check for any damaged sections but it didn't work either. The problem couldn't have been caused by my device as I've tested with different headphones and devices.

Comment: Are you using a stereo jack or a mono jack?

Comment: @Mastaxx I'm using a stereo jack

Comment: do these headphones play audio back properly when plugged in somewhere else?

Comment: @Mastaxx they don't, as I've stated in my post, other headphones work just fine while this headphone doesn't work on any devices

Comment: Wires break, or pull loose from the terminals in the phone or plug. Test continuity from the ring terminal to each headphone. If one is open, wiggle the faulty shielded cable to see if you can find the break, then repair it. You can also replace the cables.